# NAT/PAT, URL dependant, cisco 7301

Tags: networking, nat

I need to configure cisco 7301 with list of hostnames/ip's. These need to be forwarded to internal ip's/ports (depending on the hostname)

In the current setup...
www.frog.com,  ip 82.45.100.100 nat's to  internal 10.0.0.1
go to www.frog.test, firewall allows and nat's to 10.0.0.1 - no problems

But now i have a need to make it so that different URL's go to different tcp ports on server
eg.

www.frog.test - should go to 10.0.0.1:80
www.frog1.test - should go to 10.0.0.1:443

Not sure how I can do this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes more than configuring your router.  You have to configure DNS as well.

First, set up an A record for frog1.test (I assume you already have one for frog.test)

Next, you want to add an srv record to each domain record (one for frog.test, one for frog1.test).

> A SRV record record contains the following information:
>
> Service Name: the well know name of the service
>
> Protocol: specifies if this is a TCP or UDP service
>
> Domain Name: the domain name that this record belongs to
>
> TTL: Time to Live value
>
> Class: DNS class field. This always has the value of "IN"
>
> Priority: when multiple hosts are configured for the same service, the priority determines which host is tried first
>
> Weight: A relative weight for records with the same priority
>
> Port: the TCP or UDP port that the service uses
>
> Target: the name of the host providing the service

Yours will probably look like this when it's configured:

```
_www._tcp.frog.test. 86400 IN SRV 10 5 80 www.frog.test.
_www._tcp.frog1.test. 86400 IN SRV 10 5 443 www.frog1.test
```

Next we have to tell the router what to do with these connections

```
ip nat inside source static 10.0.0.1:80 82.45.100.100:80
ip nat inside source static 10.0.0.1:443 (IP address of frog1.test server):443
```

If I remember correctly, to test this on the router you type:

```
show ip nat translations
```

You should see:

```
    frog Inside global       Inside local      Outside local      Outside global 
--- 82.45.100.100:80         10.0.0.1:80           ---                 ---
```

You should also see an entry for the 443 port.

Just to make sure we understand each other, this builds a static route from your server through the router.  This won't be a DHCP set up.  This means you have to set the IP address configuration in your server (gateway address, IP, subnet mask, etc).

*Note: Doing all this from memory, and haven't had coffee yet*

Comment: I didn't realise there was so much to it, thought I'd be able to do all the router.  Thanks a lot for your help, that's given me more to look into !

Comment: Glad to be of service.  May I recommend marking this as answered?